# CreateObject Network Components

Tags: json, rest, virtual-machine, ibm-cloud-infrastructure, createobject

have been referring to the [createObject](https://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/createObject) API and as part of my request to order a virtual machine, I would like to configure the machine with both a public and a private interface. Here are the relevant parts of the JSON which works -

```
{
 "parameters":[{
         "hostname": "hostname-test",
         "domain": "domain-test",
         "startCpus": 8,
         "maxMemory": 16384,
         "hourlyBillingFlag": true,
         "operatingSystemReferenceCode": "ubuntu_14_64",
         "localDiskFlag": true,
         "privateNetworkOnlyFlag": false,
         "networkComponents": [
           {
             "maxSpeed": 1000
           }
         ]
     }]
}
```

However I would like to also set a limited public bandwidth, similar to the options presented on the web interface. Reading the [network component structure](https://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest_Network_Component) as well as the above referenced create object call, am unable to decipher the fields for choosing a specific bandwidth.

I also find no mention of the bandwidth options in getCreateObjectOptions. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

all the available options for the createObject method are displayed using this method:

https://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/getCreateObjectOptions

In regards with the network configuration the method above will return values like this:

```
"networkComponents": [
        {
            "itemPrice": {
                "hourlyRecurringFee": "0",
                "recurringFee": "0",
                "item": {
                    "description": "10 Mbps Public & Private Network Uplinks"
                }
            },
            "template": {
                "id": null,
                "networkComponents": [
                    {
                        "maxSpeed": 10
                    }
                ],
                "privateNetworkOnlyFlag": false
            }
        }
```

In the JSON above you can see the item "10 Mbps Public & Private Network Uplinks" if you want to configure that item in your order you need to follow the "template" configuration in this case it says that you need to add the follow configuration:

```
"networkComponents": [
                    {
                        "maxSpeed": 10
                    }
                ],
                "privateNetworkOnlyFlag": false
```

That's it, however the createObject method has a drawback you only can configure the options displayed by the method getCreateObjectOptions, but the portal offers many other options which are not available using the createObject method. In case you need advanced options at the moment to order you need to use the placeOrder method this article could help you to undertand the placeOrder method:

https://sldn.softlayer.com/blog/bpotter/going-further-softlayer-api-python-client-part-3

Regards

Comment: I tried following https://softlayer.github.io/rest/place_order/ but this whole concept what is an "id" is still extremely confusing. Here is a json I have come up with but I get back a status 400. Clearly am missing something which also begs the question of all the required "id"s ??

`{
 "parameters": [{
  "complexType": "SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Virtual_Guest",
  "packageId": 46,
  "location": 449494,
  "quantity": 1,
  "hardware": [{
   "hostname": "hostname-test",
   "domain": "domain.name"
  }],
  "prices": [
   {"id": 37174} # OS
  ]
 }]
}
`

Comment: I am gonna review it, but yep its is hard to make the order and yes the ids are requerid at least the basic options for a order if you need more oprtions (like disk etc) you need to add those ids as well

Comment: well man to order a server there is a minimun of required items your json does not have all those required prices, I recomed you call the method: http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/generateOrderTemplate you need to send to the method the same values as the createObject method, but  generateOrderTemplate will return a order that you can use for the placeOrder method and you can change some prices or add others according you needs, basically the method will help you to have a working json for the palceOrder method

Comment: Well sort of that was my question as to what am missing. I did try generating the template which has been confirmed to work, however on using the generated template, to place the order, I get a 500 status now.

`{"error":"An internal system error has occurred.","code":"SoftLayer_Exception_InternalError"}`

Comment: can you publish the payload of the json?

Comment: renember that the result of the generateOrdertemplate method needs to be inserted in { "parameters":[{  resultGenertaOrderMethod  }]}

Comment: probably your json does not have that format and you are getting the error becasue that

Comment: Yes, it was missing the parameters section, missed that out as the generateOrderTemplate replaces the same.

Comment: glad you can do it :)

Answer (score 0):

Adding this here for posterity.

Here is a JSON template which can be used as a basis to build other configurations :

`{
    "parameters": [{
            "imageTemplateId": null,
            "location": "449500",
            "packageId": 46,
            "prices": [{
                "hourlyRecurringFee": ".131",
                "id": 30823,
                "recurringFee": "87",
                "item": {
                    "description": "8 x 2.0 GHz Cores"
                }
            }, {
                "hourlyRecurringFee": ".153",
                "id": 29663,
                "recurringFee": "101.5",
                "item": {
                    "description": "16 GB "
                }
            }, {
                "hourlyRecurringFee": "0",
                "id": 37204,
                "recurringFee": "0",
                "item": {
                    "description": "Ubuntu Linux 14.04 LTS Trusty Tahr - Minimal Install (64 bit)"
                }
            }, {
                "hourlyRecurringFee": ".004",
                "id": 26466,
                "recurringFee": "2.9",
                "item": {
                    "description": "100 GB (LOCAL)"
                }
            }, {
                "hourlyRecurringFee": "0",
                "id": 23070,
                "recurringFee": "0",
                "item": {
                    "description": "Reboot / Remote Console"
                }
            }, {
                "hourlyRecurringFee": ".014",
                "id": 23777,
                "recurringFee": "5",
                "item": {
                    "description": "1 Gbps Private Network Uplink"
                }
            }, {
                "hourlyRecurringFee": "0",
                "id": 34183,
                "item": {
                    "description": "0 GB Bandwidth"
                }
            }, {
                "hourlyRecurringFee": "0",
                "id": 34807,
                "recurringFee": "0",
                "item": {
                    "description": "1 IP Address"
                }
            }, {
                "hourlyRecurringFee": "0",
                "id": 27023,
                "recurringFee": "0",
                "item": {
                    "description": "Host Ping"
                }
            }, {
                "hourlyRecurringFee": "0",
                "id": 32500,
                "recurringFee": "0",
                "item": {
                    "description": "Email and Ticket"
                }
            }, {
                "hourlyRecurringFee": "0",
                "id": 32627,
                "recurringFee": "0",
                "item": {
                    "description": "Automated Notification"
                }
            }, {
                "hourlyRecurringFee": "0",
                "id": 33483,
                "recurringFee": "0",
                "item": {
                    "description": "Unlimited SSL VPN Users & 1 PPTP VPN User per account"
                }
            }, {
                "hourlyRecurringFee": "0",
                "id": 35310,
                "recurringFee": "0",
                "item": {
                    "description": "Nessus Vulnerability Assessment & Reporting"
                }
            }],
            "quantity": 1,
            "sourceVirtualGuestId": null,
            "sshKeys": [{
                "sshKeyIds": [
                    12345
                ]
            }],
            "useHourlyPricing": true,
            "virtualGuests": [{
                "domain": "domain.test",
                "hostname": "hostname.test"
            }],
            "complexType": "SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Virtual_Guest"
        }]
    }`

**Required ID's:**

1. package id - obtained from [SoftLayer_Product_Package->getAllObjects](https://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Package/getAllObjects) - it is the field "id"
2. price id - obtained from [SoftLayer_Product_Package->getItemPrices](https://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Package/getItemPrices) - once again it is the field id (note there are several places where the same field name is used). This lists all the possible configurations that can go into a virtual machine. The above JSON selects a few of the options.

Finally with the JSON template, the order can be verified and placed.

(PS: Have tested this only with a virtual machine order. The SSH Key ID is an example and should be replaced with a valid ID.)